# How to add padding from left right only for label in uitable cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How to add padding from left right only for label in `UITableViewCell`?

Here is my code:

```m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellmessage";
SendMessageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SendMessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
NSDictionary *dict = [self->serverArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
cell.celllab.text= [dict objectForKey:@"message"];



CGFloat fixedWidth = cell.celllab.frame.size.width;
CGSize newSize = [cell.celllab sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
CGRect newFrame = cell.celllab.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height + 10);
cell.celllab.frame = newFrame;
cell.celllab.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
cell.celllab.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


//cell.celllab.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
//cell.celllab.layer.borderWidth = 10.0;

CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shape.frame = cell.celllab.bounds;
//shape.path = maskPath.CGPath;
shape.lineWidth = 3.0f;
shape.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
[cell.celllab.layer addSublayer:shape];


if([[dict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"u2a"])
{
    cell.celllab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    cell.celllab.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.91 blue:0.26 alpha:1];
    cell.celllab.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    cell.blackarrow.hidden = YES;
    cell.greenarrow.hidden = NO;

    cell.bmwatch.hidden = YES;
    cell.swiliam.hidden = NO;

    cell.greenmsg.hidden = NO;
    cell.whitemsg.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    cell.celllab.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.celllab.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.celllab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


    cell.greenarrow.hidden = YES;
    cell.blackarrow.hidden = NO;

    cell.bmwatch.hidden = NO;
    cell.swiliam.hidden = YES;

    cell.greenmsg.hidden = YES;
    cell.whitemsg.hidden = NO;

}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Try using a custom cell with autolayout. So that you can easily customise it.

Comment: I am new in iphone developement please explain me with example and code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this example of `UITableViewCell` customisation http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

Comment: yourView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SendMessageTableViewCell class write below function to change the frames of its subviews

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews{
       self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(rightPadding, topPadding,self.frame.size.width -      (2*rightPadding), self.frame.size.height-(2*topPadding)) 
    }
```

Above code in your custom class will be called when your cell contents subviews changes their frame and at that time you can give padding to your lable and also can change other contents frames.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.Just subclass the uilabel and write this method

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 5, 0, 5};
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```